# MySQL - Connect three different tables in transposed fashion

Tags: mysql, transpose

I have three tables:

```
business:

id     name
1      Charlie's Bakery
2      Mark's Pizza
3      Rob's Market


balanco_manual:

id      business_id   year     unit
012     1             2015     ones
123     1             2014     tens
364     2             2014     cents


conta_balanco:

id       conta    balanco_id      valor
412      12.3            012      12324
344      12.5            012      54632
414      14.1            364     344122
789      12              364    2312415
646      12              123        342
```

I need to combine them all in the `business` table and make them look like this:

```
business:

id     name                 12.3-2015    12.5-2015  11.56-2015    12-2014 2015-unit   2014-unit
1      Charlie's Bakery         12324        54632         NaN        342  ones            tens
2      Mark's Pizza               NaN          NaN         NaN    2312415     NaN         cents
3      Rob's Market               NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN    NaN            NaN
```

Explaining a little bit further: the business table has basic registries about the businesses, balanco_manual has yearly information of each one of those businesses and conta_balanco has details of the yearly information in balanco_manual.

Trying to put that last table into words:
- First I need to join business with balanco_manual, combining the "id" column in business with the "business_id" column in balanco_manual. Note that I combine unit and year in one single column named "[year]-unit". Let's call this table "new_business" to make it easir to understand
- After, I need to combine "new_business" with conta_balanco in a similar way we did with the "unit" column. Each "conta" should be combined with the year and become a column "conta-[year]".

I'm quite a beginner with SQL and I'm having interesting difficulties. Could someone help me to crack that out?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code